# UIKit doesn't release controller if it is not removed with animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In a tab bar based application, If I have one controller pushed in the navigation stack from one tab and then, when another tab is active, I try to pop that controller, it doesn't get released unless I pop it without animation.

This works:

```
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

And this does not:

```
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Does anyone have any idea of what's happening here?
Is the `animated` parameter being used improperly?

UPDATE:

Apple informed me that this is indeed a bug in UIKit, and they marked it as urgent and assigned somebody to it. It may have been resolved in the latest releases but I didn't have the time to check.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in UIKit.  If you can confirm it with a simple project, submit it to Apple.

Comment: I just created a sample project to confirm it, and I can do that. Of course it is not something that's happening with *every* use of UINavigationController. It happens if you have a UITabBarController with a navigation controller inside one tab, and from another tab you pop the navigation controller. What I noticed is that, if you have more than 1 view controller in the stack, they all get released except the last one, that remains retained until you select back the other tab (the one with the navigation controller).

Comment: If by the "last" controller you mean the root controller, then this is pertinent: "If the view controller at the top of the stack is the root view controller, this method does nothing... you cannot pop the last item on the stack." (From the documentation for `popViewControllerAnimated:`.) You very seldom have to worry about  when UIKit releases objects. Just make sure you do your part of the memory management. Who knows, maybe the frameworks hold on to an object to recycle it later? Or maybe not. The point is, you can rely on them to be well-tested.

Comment: Of course I know that the root controller cannot be popped (I was not refering to it with "last") :) The problem is that I have some observers setup in the controller that is not deallocated (it is not the root controller) and I really need the dealloc method to be called! I don't want a phantom controller to receive observer notifications... I know that this sounds really *strange* to be a bug by Apple. But I have sent a bug request anyway, with an example project demonstrating it, since it costs nothing!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. Is there any updates on this issue? Did apple ever get back to you?

Comment: They marked the bug as Duplicate and classified as a Serious Bug, but I don't know anything about the issue being solved or not. Maybe I should try to contact them again.

Comment: How did you end up solving this problem on your app?  I'm thinking about potentially redesigning the app to not use the nested tab bar + nav controller.

Comment: Ugh. It's now April 2012 and this bug is still present in iOS 5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what Dshutsi suggests is right. If you want the notifications to be removed, that is better called in the viewDidUnload method of the controller. This method is called when the controller is unloaded from the stack. I am just quoting this because we cannot vote up the comment as an answer.

Comment: In the documentation it is written that viewDidUnload is called only in low-memory conditions. I guess this is not the case. While this is not really the answer I was looking for (the controller *should* be released), I will accept it since it is the only working solution besides passing YES to the animated parameter! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the main problem are the observed notifications, why not remove the observers in the "-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated" - method?

Comment: Because I still want the notification to be received if the controller is hidden (for example the user selects another tab). I think that viewWillDisappear: is called every time the controller is not shown in the display, isn't it?

Comment: You could try viewDidUnload method which should be called when the view is released from it's controller.
Have a look at the documentation on: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW36